# wordpress blank page for add/edit page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, file-permissions

https://dream3d.ca/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page

this page is blank and ive done a lot of troubleshooting steps.

this is a fresh install on ubuntu 21.04, no plugins are activated(except health check), set to default twenty twenty two theme, i enabled wp_debug to true, increased the memory size to 512 put in this

ini_set(‘pcre.recursion_limit’,20000000);
ini_set(‘pcre.backtrack_limit’,10000000);

i cleared my browser cache still nothing.

i ran these commands on my ubuntu in wordpress root.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
chown www-data:www-data  -R *
```

these commands resolves my updating issues…

i installed the plugin health check and checked for plug incompatibilities and file integrity it it says the health check highest php 5.6 i run 8.0(7.4 for debugging this website) atm but when i didnt have it on there the issue persisted and file integrity only reported the missing sample config.

i reuploaded it incase files were corrupted but nothing.

i tried reinstalling wordpress as the only thing i havent done yet but i got these errors

```
Warning: copy(/home/dream3d/public_html/wp-config-sample.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 309

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Warning: copy(/home/dream3d/public_html/wp-config-sample.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 309

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Warning: copy(/home/dream3d/public_html/wp-config-sample.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 309

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173

Warning: copy(/home/dream3d/public_html/wp-config-sample.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 309

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/dream3d/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 173
```

but i still cant seem to get anything to show. i have nothing else to try.

wp-config
https://pastebin.com/BJts46nc

nginx server config
https://pastebin.com/KmAyGVXg

im out of ideas…what else have i not tried.